# Setting Up Multiple Domains (plus wildcard subdomains) to Point to the Same Site/VirtualHost

Tags: apache-2.2, domain, subdomain, virtualhost, wildcard

I have my primary domain with wildcard subdomains setup already.

`username.maindomain.com` and `maindomain.com`

I want to provide my users with additional domains that they can select.

`additional1.com`, `additional2.com`, `additional3.com`...

These additional domains would also need to support wildcard subdomains (as the subdomains route to a username).

Anyone know how to properly configure this in DNS and VirtualHost config?

Currently I have the additional domains as A records pointing to the same IP as my main domain (with a wildcard subdomain A record for each as well). In my VirtualHost config I am placing the additional domain names in the ServerAlias directive.

Let me know if any more detail is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you've already written how to do it:

Create A resource records for `example.com` and `*.example.com`, then add `ServerAlias example.com *.example.com` to the appropriate VirtualHost in your Apache httpd configuration. [ServerAlias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#serveralias) can occur multiple times inside a VirtualHost container.

Comment: The issue was in how I was setting up my DNS records. I needed a set of records for each domain, where I was trying to add multiple records for different domains under my primary domain.